# Altering field name using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am using the `Alter Field` tool in ArcMap to change the name of an attribute column of a shapefile. But, I am getting this error, How can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the feature class whose attribute table column name is to edited has to be in a *geodatabase*. So, first import the shapefile into a geodatabase and then run the `Alter Field` tool.

Comment: A shapefile can't be *in* a geodatabase. Esri uses the generic term "feature class" to refer to all data source types.

Comment: So, what I did was that import the shapefile into a `.gdb` to make the tool work. Before, the shapefile was in a folder, and when I gave that file to the tool, it gave that error.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid use of shapefiles, which has the side effect of making the naming and type limitations of dBase disappear.